# How come LOL download is stuck at 5200.6 MB

Tags: league-of-legends

Can I have some help with this?  The percentage is increasing... it's at 7% now.

Comment: it is probably applying the patches or running a check to see which files need to be downloaded next.

Comment: Nice internet! 8gb in less than an hour! But just be patient and let the client download what it needs to, you can check out the client in the meantime, maybe check out the store, or the champions or whatever to get acquianted with it.

Comment: Oh... nonononono @Aequitas.  I restarted, and it just went to 5600.  lol.

Answer (score 2):

*Based on my understanding of updates from software development unrelated to LoL:*

The reason for this is that updates do not consist solely of downloading.

Generally there is a file or files that are downloaded and then these files need to be:

**Uncompressed** (if the files were compressed to save space),

**Verified** (checking to ensure that the files got sent correctly and contain the right 'stuff') and

**Applied**/installed (moving the files to the correct locations, deleting files, adding/removing/changing contents of files, etc.)

After this set of files is done updating, the download will continue with the rest of the updates.

Comment: So.. how long does LoL usually take to download?  (first-time, i mean)

Comment: @Daneolog well I first downloaded it when it was in beta, and have been only updating it ever since, so don't really know how long the first time would take, especially given it seems the game downloads differently now that there is a new client. How long it takes is going to depend on your internet speed primarily and as well as your disk drive speed. Ther's not really much you can do besides wait, maybe just leave it on overnight? Alternatively if you have a friend with the game ask them to put it on a usb or other physical drive to give to you as that could be quicker and use less bandwidth

Comment: @Aequitas That probably wouldn't work. The game isn't just a folder, it also has registry keys and so it can't just be copied and pasted.

Comment: @Daneolog It's entirely dependent on your ISP and download speed. An hour or two isn't too bad, just do something else (that doesn't consume bandwidth) while it downloads.

Comment: @mbomb007 it does work, I've done it before. You can even play it directly off a USB last time I tried. and even if there's been some change since I last did it that prevented it, it would still drastically reduce how much had to be downloaded, the league client would verify the files it had, work out what it still needed to download/install and do it.